# Iphone as a start button

Tags: ios, iphone, controller

I would like to develop an (personal) iphone app to use the iPhone as a controller for a small device such as a fan or for example a light bulb. Does anyone know if there is some kind of controllable iphone-dock to use for something like this. And are there some kind of methods to use with such a dock? For example the fan just needs a variable voltage for different rpm.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EAAccessory` requires that you become a Apple hardware partner, which is very expensive and not easy (this is why you only see large companies releasing hardware accessories for iOS devices).

There's a few ways around this. The easiest way is to have your app send [OSC signals](http://opensoundcontrol.org/) over WIFI to an OSC server. I've set this up before using [TouchOSC](http://hexler.net/software/touchosc) on the iPhone and an [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) connected to my desktop via USB. It's not hard at all, but it requires that you have an Arduino connected to a computer; it's not ideal.

Alternatively you can use audio output to send commands over the line output in the iPhone's dock connector, effectively [turning the iPhone into a software modem](http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1274970878).

Good luck and if you get this figured out, post the code on github. :-D

Comment: Well the WIFI idea is great but i would like to use this in a mobile environment, a car for example. No WIFI, no computer, just the iphone.. And the iPhone needs to play audio at the same time, so i don't know if the line out works with that. Could i use the line out while docked to an normal speaker dock?

Answer (score 1):

EAAccessory framework might not be what you want because of the requirement for you to have the license and hardware. You could better implement some sort of small webserver that runs an arduino or something similar. check [this](http://hackaday.com/2011/03/17/the-basics-of-controlling-an-arduino-with-php/) out for an example of that. on the arduino, you could just have a 5v relay to control the switch of whatever device and have the other pins of the relay connected to a hot (or cold depending on the relay state) standard 120v plug so you can plug anything into it. [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Controlled-Relay-Box/) is a good project for arduino controlled relay

for direct serial control, you could do something like [this](http://devdot.wikispaces.com/Iphone+Serial+Port+Tutorial) but it would require being jailbroken. i think for a personal app, doing it via wifi would be the best way unless you jailbreak and install the full bluetooth stack where you do not need EAAccessory stuff

Comment: The iPhone needs to play audio at the same time, so i don't know if the line out works with that. Could i use the line out while docked to an normal speaker dock?

Comment: the line out on the dock should be just as accessible as the speaker port since you dont really address them individually. the phone/iOS does that automatically. Using the method of control via wifi and a php server as i linked above does not require the use of line out so you can still play sounds while doing this. basically all you would need to do on the phone is send the commands via http to the listening webserver and interpret them from there. your iphone app would be a simple app that just sent those messages (and did whatever else like play sound)

Answer (score 0):

Check out EAAccessory Framework. Used to handle external devices.

Comment: "requires that you become a Apple hardware partner, which is very expensive and not easy (this is why you only see large companies releasing hardware accessories for iOS devices)."

Comment: +1 Do you think that without using EAFramework can we control a external device. I think apple wont approve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an ultrasound detector attached to your device, and playing an audio file at the appropriate frequency etc. on the iPhone.

Comment: Nice idea, but i would like my iphone to play music at the same time!